# Java, how to create a class similar to Math

Tags: java, class, math, methods, package

I am trying to write a porting of glm in java.

At the moment I created a package jglm and inside this package there are all the different classes Mat4, Vec4, Vec3, etc..

Such as:

```
public class Mat {

    protected float[] matrix;
    protected int order;
}
```

I can call them by typing

```
jgml.Mat4 modelviewMatrix = new Jgml.Mat4(1.0f);
```

And this is fine..

Now I am writing also some methods, like

```
mix(x, y, lerp)
```

And I also would like to use this as stated, that is

```
float value = jglm.mix(x, y, lerp)
```

But of course in this case Jglm must be a class...

Is there a way to conjugate the two things together?

Edit: If I create a class jglm.Jglm

```
package jglm;

/**
 *
 * @author gbarbieri
 */
public class Jglm {

    public class Mat {

        protected float[] matrix;
        protected int order;
    }

    public class Mat4 extends Mat {

        public Vec4 c0;
        public Vec4 c1;
        public Vec4 c2;
        public Vec4 c3;

        public Mat4(float value) {

            order = 4;

            matrix = new float[16];

            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                matrix[i * 5] = value;
            }
            c0 = new Vec4(matrix, 0);
            c1 = new Vec4(matrix, 4);
            c2 = new Vec4(matrix, 8);
            c3 = new Vec4(matrix, 12);
        }

        public float[] toFloatArray() {
            return new float[]{
                c0.x, c0.y, c0.z, c0.w,
                c1.x, c1.y, c1.z, c1.w,
                c2.x, c2.y, c2.z, c2.w,
                c3.x, c3.y, c3.z, c3.w,};
        }
    }

    public static float mix(float start, float end, float lerp) {
        return (start + lerp * (end - start));
    }
}
```

When I try to instantiate

```
cameraToClipMatrix_mat4 = new Jglm.Mat4(1.0f);
```

I get "*an enclosing instance that contains Jglm.Mat4 is required*"

Comment: declare methods as static

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> At the moment I created a package Jglm and inside this package there are all the different classes Mat4, Vec4, Vec3, etc..

In Java, packages must be named in all lowercase. Naming it the way you did will surprise anyone who looks at your code and may also cause serious name-resolution issues for the compiler.

It is also customary to *import* all classes we are using so we refer to them just by their simple name in code. Perhaps you could consider declaring

```
package org.example.jglm;

public class Jglm {
  public static void mix(double x, double y, Lerp lerp) {
    ...
  }
}
```

on the client side, you'd write

```
import org.example.Jglm;

void someMethod() {
  Jglm.mix(x,y,lerp);
}
```

In general, when you need some pure functions in your code, then declare them as `static` methods. Look at [`java.lang.Math`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/lang/Math.java/) source code for guidance.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip on the naming.. I modified it.

However I still have problems, look at append

Comment: Do not put other classes inside `Jglm`. All those should be top-level classes inside the same package.

Comment: Ok, so at the end I will have my classes such as jgml.Mat and methods jgml.Jgml.mix?

Comment: ...and you'll never write `jgml.Mat`, but just `Mat`. That's how it is done in Java. You must unlearn the habits you have transfered from the languages you have been using before starting with Java.

Comment: OK, just for the sake of your interest, you *could* declare `public static class Mat` inside the `Jglm` class. That would give you what you are looking for, but it would not be what any other Java user would expect, or want, to find in your library.

Answer (score 2):

Declare all your methods in  `Mat` class as `static`

> which have the static modifier in their declarations, should be invoked with the class name, without the need for creating an instance of the class.

Ex: `ClassName.methodName(args)`

See *Class Methods* in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: But then it would be Mat.method

Comment: Yes.Exactly.What you are expecting?

Comment: Then put the static methods in a class called Jglm. They can invoke implementations in other classes if you want.

Comment: As @PatriciaShanahan said ..make Jglm class seperate and put all static methods in that class

Answer (score 1):

Having all the methods in your Jglm class as static will enable the method calls, both by instance and by classname.

Comment: If I try to copy and past Mat inside Jgml class, when I instatiate Mat I get "an enclosing instance that contains Jglm.Mat4 is required"